# Change detection on mouse move

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

In my Angular app I have a **get** property that simply returns a variable from a service.
I have put an incremental variable in it and I noticed that is is called every time I move the mouse.
I think that this could be a big performance killer.
I read that Change Detection is triggered on http request or button click, but in my case it is triggered on every mouse movemente.
Moving the mouse around tha screen trigger thousand of change detecting in few second.
In all my app I never handled the mouse move event.
This behaviur persist even in prodMode.

Is this normal?

This is a snippet of my code:

**Component.ts:**

```
export class ImplantDataComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private configSvc: ConfigurationService) {}

    static i = 0;
    public get implantData(): ImplantData {
        console.log(ImplantDataComponent.i++);
        return this.configSvc.implantData;
    }
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <dx-number-box [(value)]="implantData.delay"></dx-number-box>
</div>
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker? it's probably something inside `dx-number-box` then. And does banana in the box syntax work OK with the `value`?

Comment: I can't reprouce that behaviour in Plunker but digging into the problem I noticed that it is related to DevExtreme. I opened an issue on their githib: https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme/issues/756